# When should a DNS entry be cached? What conditions should not be? How do I determine the TTL?

Tags: network, dns

I'm writing a DNS resolver and am building a spreadsheet of when a DNS record should be cached, and not be cached... but it's harder than it first looks (to me at least).

Is there consolidated test cases for DNS caching that I can refer to?  All the RFCs seem to have many revisions, and the requirements on caching are inconsistent at best.  This is further complicated by the re-definitions of the SOA record.

An improperly cached DNS record can mean that I'm poisoning the cache with invalid records.

The most relevant example I can think of is where a fake referral is generated for an NS, A, or MX.

1. When should validation of that referral be done?
2. How is that referral validated?
3. Should I traverse from the root servers again?

Answer (score 1):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_cache_poisoning and the many entries linked from there.

A short answer would be that you should only cache the answer when it comes from a server that you would normally trust for the the relevant domain.

Comment: Aye, there is the rub.  I'm having trouble defining what 'normal' is.  What are the conditions in which a record should be cached?